# Use constant colors in matplotlib axes3d

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors, 3d, scatter-plot

I am making a 3d scatterplot with Matplotlib, with the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

for i in range(len(model.ut[0,:]-1)):
    x_dp = model.ut[0,i]
    y_dp = model.ut[1,i]
    z_dp = model.ut[2,i]
    ax.scatter(x_dp, y_dp, z_dp, marker='^')
    
for i in range(len(model.cluster_centers[:,0]-1)):
    x_c = model.cluster_centers[i,0]
    y_c = model.cluster_centers[i,1]
    z_c = model.cluster_centers[i,2]
    ax.scatter(x_c, y_c, z_c, marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('Dimension 0')
ax.set_ylabel('Dimension 1')
ax.set_zlabel('Dimension 2')
ax.set_title('3d')

pyplot.show()
```

Where `model.ut` and `cluster_center` are matrices with the data that I want to visualize.

Currently, the color of each datapoint is different:

[image]

Instead, I would like each point with the same marker to be the same color (like it has been done [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-scatter3d-py)). How can I do this?

Comment: Can't you remove the loops and do `ax.scatter(model.ut[0,:], ...)`?

Comment: Thanks, that works!